# Spring r2dbc + actuator not collecting metrics

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-starter, spring-micrometer, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I have set up a Spring boot application using version 2.2.2.RELEASE with both `spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc` and `spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-r2dbc` on the classpath. I am however unable to see any r2dbc metrics on the actuator endpoint, even though I'm doing DB queries through the application.

My understanding is that metrics should be auto collected as per [ConnectionPoolMetricsAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-r2dbc/blob/0.1.0.M3/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-r2dbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/r2dbc/ConnectionPoolMetricsAutoConfiguration.java). I have debugged my code though and this class is never touched by the spring boot initialization. What am I doing wrong?